# javascript list value iteration to specific index back and forth

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript like:

```
var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla"]
var index = [2, 3] // cat and dog
var to = 5 // fish

var arrTemp = [];

data.forEach(function(val,key){

  if(index.indexOf(key)!=-1){

    data.splice((to+1),0,data[key]);
    to++;
    delete data[key];

  }
})
data = data.filter(function(val){ return val != undefined }); 

console.log(data)
```

Here `index = [2, 3]` is the index of the `data` i. e. `ball and dog` and `to` is the `target` where I want to place the `index` value.

I want to put `index` i. e `ball and dog` after `fish`.

The above code gives the exact result and was helped by a user from SO.

But when I put index value to `index = [4, 5]` and `to = 2` . It gives me error. It does not place the `elephant` and `fish` after `cat`.

I have written another program to handle this like:

```
var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla"]
var index = [4, 5] // elephant and fish
var to = 2 // cat
var offset = 0

data.forEach(function(val,key){


  if(index.indexOf(key)!=-1){
    data.splice((to+1), 0, data[key + offset]);
    to++;
    offset++;
    var del_key = key + offset
    delete data[del_key];
  }
});
console.log(data)
```

This code gives result for `index =  [4, 6]` or `index = [3, 6]` and `to = 2` but not for like `index=[4, 5]` and `to = 2`

Comment: `[2,3]` is `cat` and `dog` not `ball` and `dog`

Comment: @gotnull sorry that was typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an Elegant solution as far the algorithm is concerned but it does the job. Tell me if you find anything wrong

```
var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla"]
var index = [0, 4, 5] 
var to = 2; 
var i =0;
var stringatTo = data[to];
var temp =[];
for (var k = 0; k < index.length; k++) {
    temp[k] = data[index[k]];
}

for (var k = 0; k < index.length; k++) {
  data.splice(data.indexOf(temp[k]),1);
}

var curindex = data.indexOf(stringatTo);

for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
data.splice(curindex+1+j,0,temp[j]);
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on all cases. Ask any questions if needed.

```js
var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla"];
var index = [0,4,6]; // elephant and fish
var to = 2; // cat
var offset = 0;
var change = (to < index[0] ? 1 : 0);

console.log(data);
for(var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
    var key = index[i];
    data.splice((to+1), 0, data[key + offset]);
    delete data[key + offset + (to < key ? 1 : 0)];
    to++;
    offset += ((to+1) < key ? 0 : 1);
}
data = data.filter(function(val){ return val != undefined }); 
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hmm, I though it was representing a range. I'll have to correct it. --> DONE

Comment: Still doesn't work for cases like : `index = [0, 4, 5];` I'll check it tomorrow. Almost 2am here.

Comment: Finally, I fixed before going to bed.

Comment: Here is the issue man.. `index = [2, 3]` and ` to = 5` ... not working for this..

Answer (score 0):

This works in all cases. Try it.

```
var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla"];
var index = [0,4,5];  
var to = 2;
var arrTemp = [];
data.forEach(function(val,key){
  if(index.indexOf(key)!=-1){
    data.splice(key,1);
    data.splice(to>key?(to):(to+1),0,val);
    to>key?to:to++;
  }
});
data = data.filter(function(val){ return val != undefined }); 
console.log(data);
```